# How does Android Controller implement Observer containing a Runnable Observable

Tags: android, runnable, observable, observers

I am writing a Cowndown timer, and I have a countdowntimerController, which implements the Observer interface. It has an internal class called countdown, which extends the Observable class and implements the Runnable interface. However, my controller does not get notified when the runnable finishes. Below are my codes, please tell me where I got wrong. P.S. since the Observer is inside the Observable, I used countdown.addObserver(this), would that be the problem?

```
public class CountdownTimerController extends ActivityController implements Observer {
    private Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    private void startTimer(int posi) {
        /* some countdown timer codes */
        Countdown countdown = new Countdown();
        countdown.addObserver(this);
       handler.post(countdown);
    }
    public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("countdownController", "update");
    }
    private class Countdown extends Observable implements Runnable {
        //private Handler handler = new Handler();      
        public void run() {
            long millis = countdownTime - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + pausedTime;
            if(millis <=0) {
                onFinish();
                return;
            }
            /* time calculation logic */
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }

        public void onFinish(){
            notifyObservers();
            handler.removeCallbacks(this);
        }
    };
}
```